# How can I self hide and show QDialog() in PyQT5?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a GUI that was generated using Qt Designer, I used pyuic5 to generate a .py file. In a separate py (program.py) file I import my UI a do all my work there.

**program.py**

```
import sys, os, time
from subprocess import call
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyCred_GUI import Ui_Dialog


class MyGUI(Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)


        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.cancelbutton)

    def cancelbutton(self):
        exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint)
    prog = MyGUI(dialog)

    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I pulled a lot out just to focus on the issue here. When I click my Cancel button, I want the window to hide, set a timer, and then reappear after so many seconds. I have tried every combination of self.close() self.hide() self.destroy() and none of them hide my window. I get an error that says

"**AttributeError: 'MyGUI' object has no attribute 'hide'**"

Which makes sense because MyGUI doesn't have a hide() function. I am at a complete loss on how to hide this window.

**EDIT** (Solved)
For future people, as suggested by [Hi Im Frogatto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841194/hi-im-frogatto) dialog.hide() worked.

Comment: How about `dialog.hide()`? (btw, `QDialog` isn't supposed to show your main application's UI, use `QMainWindow` instead)

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto The btw is bad advice. A `QMainWindow` should *only* be used when you need its *specific* functionality: that of dockable sub-windows, etc. It's *completely valid* to have a main UI derive from `QDialog` or `QWidget` directly. It's **unfortunate** that Qt Creator starts you with a "main ui" deriving from `QMainWindow` by default. In many cases it's precisely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @KubaOber I didn't say using `QDialog` is an invalid approach. But UX requires applications' main UI to have menu bar, status bar, etc which are provided by `QMainWindow` not bare `QWidget` or `QDialog`. Additionally a `QDialog` is supposed to be accepted or rejected not to hide and show.

Comment: Not everything is complex enough to warrant status/menu. Since you bring UX: modern screens are short and wide. A classic menu and status bar is a waste of valuable vertical space. Plenty of applications don't have a menu bar. It's a given on OS X but other than that I'd say it's highly optional. A status bar is is helpful - it you're really going for that 1995 MFC look. I have a browser and Qt Creator open and neither has a status bar, and the browser doesn't have a menu either. Neither is a toy app :) So yes, a `QMainWindow` shouldn't be used indiscriminately.

Comment: It's normal and expected to `show` a `QDialog` (as opposed to `exec()`-ing it) - that way you don't reenter the event loop. Sure you are supposed to accept or reject it, but plenty of small applications are like that. Otherwise, for a menu-less application you want `QWidget`, as I've said. Even with a menu you should consider whether the `QMainWidget` fits your use case.

Comment: @Hi I'm Frogatto, can you move your dialog.hide() to an answer so I can mark that is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, `dialog` is of type `QDialog` and thereby having `hide` method. However instances of `MyGUI` class seem to not have such a method. So, if you write `dialog.hide()` in that `__init__()` function, you can hide it.